# How to keep image alignment when cropping in Python?

Tags: python, html, css, image, user-experience

I'm trying to crop and resize images in Python, and I want them to be in a fixed format
afterwards (47x62 Pixels). However, if the original image is in landscape, my algorithm doesn't work, there are blank areas.

```
import Image, sys

MAXSIZEX = 47
MAXSIZEY = 62

im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
(width, height) = im.size

ratio = 1. * MAXSIZEX / MAXSIZEY

im = im.crop((0, 0, int(width*ratio), int(height*ratio)))
im = im.resize((MAXSIZEX, MAXSIZEY), Image.ANTIALIAS)

im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

I want the resized image to be fully 47x62 - there should be no empty area visible.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if `MAXSIZEX` is greater then the width or the `MAXSIZEY` is greater than the height. If they are first rescale the image and then do the cropping:

```
MAXSIZEX = 64
MAXSIZEY = 42
width, height = im.size

xrat = width / float(MAXSIZEX)
yrat = height / float(MAXSIZEY)

if xrat < 1 or yrat < 1:
    rat = min(xrat, yrat)
    im = im.resize((int(width / rat), int(height / rat)))
res = im.crop((0, 0, MAXSIZEX, MAXSIZEY))
res.show()
```

Comment: +1 for old, self explanatory code. Touch from inside vs touch from outside

Answer (score 0):

Chosing x/y as the scaling is an implicit assumption that your source's y dimension will always be smaller relative to your target resolution than your source's x dimension.  First, figure out which dimension to scale on, then crop:

```
width_count = float(width) / MAXSIZEX
height_count = float(height) / MAXSIZEY
if width_count == height_count:
    pass
elif width_count < height_count:
    im = im.crop(0, 0, width, int(width_count * height / height_count))
else:
    im = im.crop(0, 0, int(height_count * width / width_count), height)
```

Now you know you have the largest subimage from the original that matches your target aspect ratio, so you can resize without warping the image.